# Google Maps - How To Have MyLocation Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've been doing a little HTML and JavaScript coding with Google maps, but I just can't figure out how to track the user as they move. I am able to show the user location on the map with a marker, but I want it to move as the user moves. Pretty much the same thing as the MyLocation button on Google Maps. Does anyone know how it works? If you can explain how it works, that will be a big help.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    if (navigator.geolocation) { 
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  

var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                   position.coords.longitude);

// Initialize the Google Maps API v3
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom: 15,
  center: point,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// Place a marker
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: point,
  map: map
  });
 }); 
} 
 else {
 alert('W3C Geolocation API is not available');
} 
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 15,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

var marker = null;

function autoUpdate() {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
var newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                      position.coords.longitude);

if (marker) {
  // Marker already created - Move it
  marker.setPosition(newPoint);
}
else {
  // Marker does not exist - Create it
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: newPoint,
    map: map
  });
}

// Center the map on the new position
map.setCenter(newPoint);
 }); 

 // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
 setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);
  }

 autoUpdate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather leave this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation points so...
I think what you're after is `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);`
Follow that up with onSuccess and onError functions:

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var currentLong = position.coords.longitude;
    //re map them here
    clearMarkers();
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map
     });
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    window.navigator.alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you figured this out but you don't actually need the vars `currentLat` and `currentLong`.  Those were just for if you wanted the coords for something else.  You could also make this a little more efficient by declaring your initial marker as a global variable with `myMarker=new google.maps.Marker({ ... });` and then updating it's position in the `onSuccess()` function.  Could even animate it for a nice effect.

Comment: If this worked for you would you mind marking it as the accepted answer?  Trying to get my rep up.  Thanks.